# ConcourseCI - docker-image resource issue; mount: permission denied (are you root?)

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, concourse

I have concourse 3.8.0 running on my workstation which is Ubuntu 17.04 and 
here is my pipeline definition:

```
---
jobs:
- name: job-docker-image-resource
  public: true

  plan:
  - get: "golang_tools_docker_image"
  - task: docker-image-resource
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source: {repository: busybox}
      run:
        path: echo
        args: [docker-image-resource]

resources:
- name: "golang_tools_docker_image"
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: "golang"
    tag: "1.9.2-alpine3.7"

resource_types:
- name: docker-image
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: concourse/docker-image-resource
    tag: docker-1.12.6
```

And here is the output:

[image]

This works fine in concourse 2.7.7.  I haven't tried any versions between 2.7.7 and 3.8.0 yet.

Comment: Concourse doesn't use your host docker, it brings its own. Are you running the worker `concourse worker` as `root`?

Comment: A ha..that’s good to know.  How would I find out which version of docker ships with a given version of concourse? Is it possible the host docker is interfering with the embedding docker?   I am yes, first thing I checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `privileged: true` on the resource type definition:

```
resource_types:
- name: docker-image
  privileged: true
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: concourse/docker-image-resource
    tag: latest
```

Comment: Great..did I miss that in the docs or is it missing from the docs?