# ConcourseCI in Docker: mount: permission denied (are you root?)

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, concourse

Running a simple "Hello World" pipeline with ConcourseCI 3.13.0 running inside Docker (docker-compose) causes the following error:

```
mount: permission denied (are you root?)
```

My setup is as follows:

Alpine Linux VM running docker-compose with the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  concourse-db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_DB=concourse
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=concourse_pass
    - POSTGRES_USER=concourse_user
    - PGDATA=/database
    volumes:
    - ./database:/database

  concourse-web:
    image: concourse/concourse
    command: web
    links:
    - concourse-db
    depends_on:
    - concourse-db
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
    - "./keys/web:/concourse-keys"
    environment:
    - CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_HOST=concourse-db
    - CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_USER=concourse_user
    - CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=concourse_pass
    - CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_DATABASE=concourse
    - CONCOURSE_BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME=myuser
    - CONCOURSE_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD=mypass

  concourse-worker:
    image: concourse/concourse
    command: worker
    privileged: true
    links:
    - concourse-web
    depends_on:
    - concourse-web
    volumes:
    - ./keys/worker:/concourse-keys
    environment:
    - CONCOURSE_TSA_HOST=concourse-web:2222
    - CONCOURSE_GARDEN_NETWORK
```

The pipeline I try to run is the following:

```
---
jobs:
- name: job-hello-world
  public: true
  plan:
  - task: hello-world
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source: {repository: busybox}
      run:
        path: echo
        args: [hello world]
```

The concourse worker (inside Docker) is running as root:

```
host:~/concourse# ps aux
....
16466 root       0:00 /usr/local/bin/concourse worker
....
```

---

I know, there is the following question: [ConcourseCI - docker-image resource issue; mount: permission denied (are you root?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327705/concourseci-docker-image-resource-issue-mount-permission-denied-are-you-roo), unfortunately I can't figure out how to define "priviledged" for a "image_resource" of a task

I tried the following pipeline and got the same error:

```
---
jobs:
- name: job-hello-world
  public: true
  plan:
  - task: hello-world
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source: {repository: busybox}
      run:
        path: echo
        args: [hello world]
resource_types:
- name: docker-image
  privileged: true
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: concourse/docker-image-resource
    tag: latest
```

Comment: I ran exactly the same setup using Docker on a (newly created) Ubuntu 18.04 and it works. So, I guess this is an alpine - docker - concourse - dind issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're seeing container mount issues when you're running `privileged: true`, it's most often an [outdated kernel](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/1370) that causes this.